# Find a string in another string in R

Tags: string, r, compare

I want to find a string within another string in R.  The strings are as follows.  I want to be able to match string a to string b as and the out put should be `a == b` which returns TRUE

```
a <- "6250;7250;6251"
b <- "7250"
a == b                 #FALSE
```

Comment: What do you want your output to be?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I have edited my question. I want a == b True

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If b were to equal `725` instead of `7250`, would you still want the result to be `TRUE`?

If so then the `grepl` answer already given will work (and you could speed it up a bit by setting `fixed=TRUE` since there are no patterns to be matched.

If you only want `TRUE` when there is an exact match to something between `;` then you will either need to embed `b` into a regular expression (`sprintf` may be of help), or simpler, use `strsplit` to split `a` into just the parts to be matched, then use `%in%` to see if `b` is a match to any of those values.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `regmatches` and `gregexpr`, but your question is somewhat vague at the moment, so I'm not positive that this is what you're looking for:

```
> regmatches(a, gregexpr(b, a))
[[1]]
[1] "7250"

> regmatches(a, gregexpr(b, a), invert=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "6250;" ";6251"
```

Based on your updated question, you're probably looking for `grepl`.

```
> grepl(b, a)
[1] TRUE
> grepl(999, a)
[1] FALSE
```

^^ We're essentially saying "look for 'b' in 'a'".