# Check which words show up at least once within words from another vector

Tags: r, string, matching, cpu-word

Let's say we have a list of words:

```
words = c("happy","like","chill")
```

Now I have another string variable:

```
s = "happyMeal"
```

I wanted to check which word in words has the matching part in s. 
So s could be "happyTime", "happyFace", "happyHour", but as long as there's "happy" in there, I want my result to return the index of word "happy" in the string vector words.

This question is similar but not identical to from the question asked in the post: [Find a string in another string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791354/comparing-strings-in-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each of the words that you're searching for with `sapply`, using `grepl` to determine if that word appears in `s`:

```
sapply(words, grepl, s)
# happy  like chill 
#  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If `s` is a single word then `sapply` with `grepl` returns a logical vector that you can use to determine the words that matched:

```
words[sapply(words, grepl, s)]
# [1] "happy"
```

When `s` contains multiple words, then `sapply` with `grepl` returns a logical matrix, and you can use the column sums to determine which words showed up at least once:

```
s <- c("happyTime", "chilling", "happyFace")
words[colSums(sapply(words, grepl, s)) > 0]
# [1] "happy" "chill"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `stri_detect` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
words[stri_detect_regex(s, words)]
#[1] "happy"
```